# Restoring CSS value after jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery .toggle to show and hide a div. I have set it up so that when it toggles for the first time the background of the button that the user clicks on changes colour. What I would like to do is restore the button background colour when the user clicks the button again to show the div. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot :-)

Here is what I have so far…

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#billboardButton").click(function () {
        $("#billboard").toggle("slow", function() {
            $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", "#333");
        });
    });
}); // End document ready
</script>

<style>
#billboardButton {
background-color:#f1f1f1;
color:#666;
padding:3px;
width:100px;
cursor:pointer;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}


</style>

<div id="test" style="width:970px;margin:20px auto;">
<div>
<div id="billboardButton">Close Ad</div>
</div>
<div id='billboard' style='width:970px; height:250px;background-color:#0C9;'>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that your original background color is in the CSS files, so you can simply do this :

```
$("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", $(this).is(':not(:visible)') ? "#333" : "");
```

See the result : http://jsbin.com/ahatin/1

Comment: will not work, he has to use ***$('#billboard').is(':not(:visible)')*** because he doesn't toggle the button itself... anyhow +1, it's quite more elegant then my solution

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach `$(this)` is `#billboard` since you are in the callback function of toggle.

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach No please, it happen to everyone!

Comment: Great stuff @Karl-AndréGagnon it works a treat - What if I wanted to change the 'Close Ad' to 'Open Ad' when the div is toggled closed?

Comment: Basicly the same thing. `$('#billboardButton').text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close Ad' : 'Open Ad')`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Perfect! I was pretty close but not close enough. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create an adittional class (e.g. **buttonPressedFirst**). Now when toggling:

```
if($("#billboardButton").hasClass('buttonPressedFirst'))  {
    $("#billboardButton").removeClass('buttonPressedFirst')
} else {
    $("#billboardButton").addClass('buttonPressedFirst')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class othercolor

.othercolor
{

```
background-color:#333;
```

}

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#billboardButton").click(function () {

    $(this).toggleClass("othercolor");

});
```

});